# Selenium: button causes clickAndWait. Page loads, but Selenium stops recording more

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to record (for scraping) this site: http://www.easyjet.com/en

I enter my info in the form and then click "Show flights". This causes a Selenium command "clickAndWait". The page loads and I can click around and do stuff - but Selenium has stopped recording.

Is it possible to get past this? I'm trying Selenium because the conventional ways (Python urllib2 with cookies) didn't work for me. Thinking that they may have very purposefully stopped anyone from scraping.

Edit: I know that the page sets a cookie and does a redirect. But this should be handled by Selnium, no?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully record and playback finding a flight with the [selenium IDE for Firefox](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp). I was using version 1.0.10.